# Smarter way to print two integers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, integer, alert

In my attempt to print two JavaScript variables that were integers, next to each, other I ran into this small road bump:

Code:

```
var left = 100
var right = 100

alert(left + right)
```

Result:

```
200
```

I wanted to get back `100100`

Of course this wasn't a hard problem for me to fix, I came up with this:

```
alert(left + "" + right)
```

And that worked great!

For some reason, it doesn't feel right. Looks a little *unrefined* to me...

**Is there a smarter way to do this?**

Comment: I'd use `"" + left + right`, which would also work (it's the same as `("" + left) + right`). The issue is that `num + num -> num` (which is good for being able to do math!), but `+` is "overloaded" such that `anything + str -> str` or `str + anything -> str` (for string concatenation).

Comment: Questions about "smarter ways" to solve a problem are off-topic for Stack Overflow. You may be able to get help on [codereview.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or something like

```
alert(String(left)+String(right))
```

Comment: I kind of liked this one

Answer (score 6):

You should convert them to `string` type.

```
alert(left.toString() + right.toString())
```

The reason is, in javascript those will be `numbers` (integers) upon creation. You have to convert them to `string` type. Since those are objects, you can use their `toString()` method to convert.

[Js Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/EXyT8/)

Comment: It's already been answered

Comment: @Mike-O that should not matter, the time difference was too less between the answers.... so my +1. Why would somebody down vote this answer.

Comment: @Mike-O - Yeah, like 3 seconds earlier.

Comment: @Mike-O harsh, he answered less than a second after you.

Comment: Ok sorry guys! the answer didn't pop up at once in my browser so... you're right, was a bit harsh but I can't remove the vote. Please edit so I can upvote it

Comment: @Mike-O It's okay mate, no hard feelings! I've edited my answer for you.

Comment: @Aristona vote changed to up-vote!

Answer (score 3):

**3 options more**, besides the one you already have:

```
//make it a string from the beginning    
var left = '100' 
var right = '100'
alert(left + right)

//make it a string later   
var left = 100
var right = 100
alert(left.toString() + right)

//or
alert([left, right].join(''))
```

Comment: +1, `[left, right].join('')` as another one.

Comment: @plalx, that was nice one! added :)

Comment: And you actually dont need to use `right.toString()` if you already used `left.toString()` since there will be automatic conversion.

Comment: You could also have a small helper function. `function concat() { return [].join.call(arguments, ''); }` And use it like `concat(left, right);` That's probably about it for acceptable alternatives ;)

Answer (score 2):

You will have to convert the value to strings one way or another and adding quotes will do just that.

Else they'll end up being integers before evalutaed and therefor added.

You can also use:

```
alert(left.toString() + right.toString());
```

or a variant of what you have:

```
alert('' + left + right);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
left.toString() + right.toString()
```